# Scraping an HTML response for specific values on Apigee gateway

Tags: apigee

Has anyone determined a good method of scraping an HTML response, formatted largely in HTML5 and non-XML compliant, for specific values using the Apigee gateway.

That is to say, if I were to get the following piece of a response,

```
<input name="a" value="a1">
<input name="b" value="b1">
<input name="c" value="c1">
<input name="d" value="d1">
```

Can I return the values of a and b?

As this is html and not XML Strict, Apigee's XPATH does not work.

Alternatively, is there a recommended method of allowing DOM parsing at the gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try regex in java or javascript or py policy baseed on your preference. You can assign entire response payload to a variable as a string. Then you can do string operations such as regex match to extract specific part of the HTML text.

For XML response payload you can use XSLT and XPATH expressions.

Comment: Both this response and that by @Girish-BR could be correct, but I went with this approach and needed to pick an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the NodeJs route to do this on the gateway. Since Apigee Edge supports NodeJs out of the box, you can use NPMs to play around with the DOM. My personal favorite is Cheerio [[https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio]](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio%5d). BTW Cheerio is also based on JQuery

```
 var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
  $ = cheerio.load('<h2 class="title">Hello world</h2>');

  $('h2.title').text('Hello there!');
  $('h2').addClass('welcome');

  $.html();
 //=> <h2 class="title welcome">Hello there!</h2>
```